# How to create webpage in mule esb

Tags: jsp, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I would like to create JSP page using Mule ESB.

How could I create a JSP page?

Is it possible to deploy my Mule application with that JSP page?

When I run my Mule application; my front end page should be executed (JSP page).

How could I implement this with Mule ESB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jetty:connector in mule as embedded Jetty Server, For example:

```
<jetty:connector name="Jetty" doc:name="Jetty"
    doc:description="This is the conector to Jetty server">
    <jetty:webapps port="8060" host="localhost" directory="${app.home}/webapps" />
</jetty:connector>
```

inside webapps may have WEB-INF, jsp, images, css, js, etc.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Jetty+Transport+Reference

Hope it helps.

Comment: Julio's solution works, in fact Bookstore example shows how to do this.